# Does "UPF 13" mean anything to you?

Tags: category-theory

I have some math notes that contained some interesting stuff, but I can't make out the meaning of something I wrote nearly a year ago.

Perhaps it's misspelled or incorrect, but I'm trying to find out what I meant by:

> *"This demonstrates a motivation describing why "strong typing systems" for mathematics provide a basis for reasoning about objects and their types, **like: UPF 13, also see 'Per Martin-Löf', and "the geometric algebra" (Clifford algebras)**, abstract category theory, [...] "*

I can't find anything about what "UPF 13" possibly means, but maybe someone is familiar with a particular perspective or CAS that sounds similar?

Comment: "Ultraviolet Protection Factor (UPF)". Though $13$ is rather a low value.

Comment: It's a big stretch, but could you mean univalent foundations? No idea what the P or the 13 are doing there though. Are these notes handwritten, and if so, could you post a picture of them? (In case we're better at interpreting your handwriting than you are.)

Comment: @PatrickStevens "in case we're better at interpreting your handwriting than you are" !?! :) I laughed out loud... :)

Comment: (I would be interested to hear the reasoning for the "close as not focused enough" vote. It seems like an eminently reasonable question to me.)

Comment: The homotopy type theory book was published in 2013 by the Univalent Foundations Project, hence UFP13.

Comment: Indeed, typing ufp13 into Google yields many hits referencing the homotopy type theory book.